# Ruby on rails how create link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, gmaps4rails

Help to create link with name restaurant on the map on view show restaurant id.
controllers/maps_controller.rb

```
def index
    @maps = Map.all
    @json = Map.all.to_gmaps4rails do |map, marker|
       marker.infowindow "<a href=/restaurants/#{@restaurant.object_id}><h2>#{map.name}</h2></a>"
    end
```

and create relationships to a specific id restaurant view show
 
views\restaurants\show.html.erb

```
<%= @restaurant.title %>
```

routes.rb

```
resources :restaurants
resources :maps
```

database table

```
create_table "maps", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "address"
    t.float    "longitude"
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.boolean  "gmaps"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

create_table "restaurants", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "image_url"
    t.integer  "map_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",      :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      :null => false
```

and models

```
class Map < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :gmaps, :latitude, :longitude, :name
  acts_as_gmappable
  has_one :restaurant

    def gmaps4rails_address
      address
    end
end

class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :image_url, :title, :map_id
  belongs_to :map

end
```

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? What did you already try? What kind of error messages are you getting?

Comment: I want to make a specific reference point on the map id id title to the restaurant.
If I click on the link on the map, then all the points given the same address.http://localhost:3000/restaurants/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When iterating, right now you are fetching *the same restaurant* (`@restaurant`) for each `Map`-object. Use `map.restaurant` instead to get the correct restaurant.

Also, I would recommend to use Rails' url-helpers to create the urls instead of doing that by hand.

Lastly, writing "raw" html to an object inside of a controller is not good. Would recommend you to move the whole shebang to a helper method (at least).

So something like this:

```
Map.all.to_gmaps4rails do |map, marker|
  marker.infowindow info_for_restaurant(map.restaurant)
end

# Somewhere else in your controller
private 
def info_for_restaurant(restaurant)
  view_context.link_to restaurant_path(restaurant) do
    view_context.content_tag("h2") do
      restaurant.name
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: now there is an error
NoMethodError in MapsController#index

undefined method `info_for_restaurant' for #<MapsController:0x54733c8>

Comment: Hey sorry, I was confused about helpers. They are only available in the view. Put it in your controller instead.

Comment: no problem, now shows error No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"restaurants"}

Comment: We have to send the restaurant as an argument to the link helper. Edited the code. I'm sorry, again, to post such sloppy code. But perhaps you could have done some thinking of your own?

Comment: Can you explain please step by step, what I must do. I'm add to controller string "link_to restaurant_path(restaurant) do" now get an error: undefined method `link_to'

Comment: All these problems are due to the fact that you're doing work in the controller that really should be done in the view. I would look up some way of delegating assignment of the infowindows to the view. I think there are guides for this in the gmaps4rails wiki.

Comment: Thanx man! All works. I watched guides wiki gmaps4rals, but I did not find a description about links...

Comment: How to work with links you would have to look up in general Rails guides. What I'm talking about is not doing view-related code in the controller. Move it to a view. See for example the section called `self-explanatory example` here https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Controller

Comment: > I'm create in controller link                                     > @json = Map.all.to_gmaps4rails do |map, marker|
> marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/maps/maps_link", 
        > :layout => false, 
        > :locals => { :map => map})
    > end

Comment: but don't know what write to maps_link

Comment: Read up on rails partials: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: Crossposting? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15715599/no-route-matches-action-show-controller-restaurants