# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"restaurants"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, gmaps4rails

If I want to go with my home page clicking on the map localhost:3000/maps gets out this error No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"restaurants"}
controllers/maps_controller.rb

```
def index
    @maps = Map.all
    @json = Map.all.to_gmaps4rails do |map, marker|
       marker.infowindow info_for_restaurant(map.restaurant)
    end


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @maps }
    end
end
def show
    @map = Map.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @map }
    end
end
private 
def info_for_restaurant(restaurant)
  link_to restaurant_path do
    content_tag("h2") do
      restaurant.name
    end
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :restaurants
resources :maps
```

**This is answer for my question:**
 
controllers/maps_controller.rb

```
def index
    @maps = Map.all
    @json = Map.all.to_gmaps4rails do |map, marker| 
      marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/maps/maps_link", 
        :layout => false, :locals => { :map => map})
    end


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @maps }
    end
  end
```

views/maps/_maps_link.html.erb

```
<div class="map-link">
<h2><%= link_to map.restaurant.title, map.restaurant %></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: @json = Map.all.to_gmaps4rails do |map, marker| 
      marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/maps/maps_link", 
        :layout => false, :locals => { :map => map})

Answer (score 0):

You referred to `restaurant_path` within `info_for_restaurant`, which is part of MapsController. Rails met error here.

You need to either define the `restaurant_path` in restaurant controller, or comment out this function in maps controller at this moment.

Comment: What do I need define in restaurant controller?

Comment: @Sivard, you need at least `index` method exists in restaurant controller to make `restaurants_path` valid. And I think you need to also run `rake db:migrate` after generating restaurant controller.

Comment: Why are involved index controller action, if I make a link to show the view restaurant? And why are involved command rake db:migrate, for controller? It is for the database.

Comment: Yes, it's for `show`, I made a mistake for remembering it as plural. For rake task, if you scaffold you may leave model object in controller. Anyway that's just a reference and you decide it. The main point is the `restaunant_path` is invalid at this moment, you need to make it legal.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong in several levels. Let's work on them, one at a time:

**1) Your call to the route helper is wrong:**

`restaurant_path` is the route helper for a `show` action. A `show` action needs an `id` parameter to be valid. Your call is missing a parameter.

So, your code must be something like this:

```
def info_for_restaurant(restaurant)
  link_to restaurant_path(restaurant) do
    content_tag("h2") do
      restaurant.name
    end
  end
end
```

To see the parameters needed for each action, you can run `rake routes` on the console.

However, this does not solve the problem, as you're also:

**2) Calling view helpers from your controller**

`link_to` and `content_tag` are view helper methods, and you don't want to bother your controller with view issues. So, the best way to solve this problem is to move your `info_for_restaurant` method to a helper, and call it from a view instead.

So, now, your controller will not assign anything to `@json`, and the last line of your view will look like this:

```
<%= gmaps4rails @maps.to_gmaps4rails {|map, marker| marker.infowindow info_for_restaurant(map.restaurant) } %>
```

Comment: If I change code on info_for_restaurant get an error "undefined method `link_to'" "app/controllers/maps_controller.rb:91:in `info_for_restaurant'"
"app/controllers/maps_controller.rb:8:in `block in index'"
"app/controllers/maps_controller.rb:7:in `index'"

Comment: Move the `info_for_restaurant` method to a helper, and the `@json` assignment (the `to_gmaps4rails` call) to the view. You can't access `link_to` and `content_tag` from the controller.

Comment: Can you explain please step by step, what I must do. I'm move to maps_helper.rb code def info_for_restaurant(restaurant)...now get an error: undefined method `info_for_restaurant'

Comment: I rewrote the answer to include all the steps.

Comment: Thx, but I found answer for my question.

Comment: I wrote a response in the topic

Comment: please include it as an answer and accept it, so others can benefit.